# How to get current IO context

Tags: ruby, io

I would like to pimp certain string methods when the string is streamed to a terminal. For example, I want to rewrite `String#to_s`. I want the string to be delivered with ANSI color codes on terminals, and not if it is being written to a file. For that, I have to have access the IO where it is currently being written to. Do I have access to a variable which identifies the current read/write context?

Comment: This sounds wrong. I would prefer using printers (`TerminalPrinter`, `RawPrinter`, `HttpPrinter`, etc.)

Comment: it's not a question of wrong, it's a question of possibility. Do I have access to the IO stream or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods on string like `to_s` are so essential that modifying them would likely mess up a lot of dependent code. Rather than modifying `String` methods, you should modify the `IO` methods such as `puts`, `print`, etc. You can give different definitions to each subclass of `IO` such as `File` (polymorphism). Then, you do not need to identify the IO class.

Comment: But then I'll have to basically modify the same function many times in all the classes that implement puts, right? The current implementation is overwriting Kernel#puts and pimping the case where the argument is a string. I'd prefer to pimp the string class since that's what I want.

Comment: I am not suggesting to overwrite `Kernel#puts`, I am suggesting to overwrite subclasses of `IO#puts`.

Comment: Humm... which is the subclass responsible for writing into the terminal then? $stdout seems to be a pure IO object, no subclasses in between.

Comment: Define a singleton method on it.

Comment: This solution ended up being good enough for our specific problem. I thought I was going to overwrite an already existing #puts, but turns out neither the File class nor the Socket class have their own implementation, both of them use the superclass (IO) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`IO#isatty` is probably what you are looking for. But Sergio’s suggestion is still better choice.

[More info](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-isatty).

Comment: IO#isatty refers to identifying on an io object whether it is in terminal or not. It doesn't tell me inside a string which is the io object the string is being written to. And this is what I want, then I could use either #isatty or #tty?